# Model helper: array of strings to check against loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to figure out the best way to create a model helper for an array of strings and then use that helper to check if an each loop contains any of the strings within the helper array.

I want to create a model helper, that will simply be an array of strings:

`["Google","IBM","Surge","Apple", "8","100"]` etc.

In my model, I am using Feedzirra to import and save records.

```
entries.each do |entry|
    if entry.title ... INCLUDES ANY STRING FROM THE HELPER ARRAY

            create!(....
            )

    end
end
```

I am not sure how to:

1. Create the helper or where to put it (probably in /lib?)
2. How to include this helper after "if entry.title" in my main model

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Is this list known right now? Why not include this array as a constant in your model class and then use a validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the purpose. If this is a small list that rarely changes, you can put it in a constant:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  KEYWORDS = ["Google","IBM","Surge","Apple", "8","100"].freeze

  def title_matches?
    !self.title.scan(/#{KEYWORDS.join('|')}/).empty?
  end
end
```

Just a quick note: string matching is case-sensitive, so you may want to downcase the list items and the title before matching.

If this is a dynamic list, I'd probably store the keywords in a table: keywords(id:integer name:string). Then modify the matching method to this:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base

  def title_matches?(keywords)
    !self.title.scan(/#{keywords.join('|')}/).empty?
  end

  def self.update_from_feed!
    # Get keywords
    keywords = Keyword.pluck(:name)

    # Get entries
    entries = <code to fetch feed>

    entries.each do |entry|
      if entry.title_matches?(keywords)
        create!(....)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what direction would I head say if I had to frequently add to this list, i.e. the list constantly grew.

Comment: I modified the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, this is indeed helpful - appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Question is whether you even need a helper? You could write a very simple method doing

```
["Google","IBM","Surge","Apple", "8", "100"].any? { |str| entry.include?(str) }
```